# Imagen al revés con Instascan

Tags: javascript

Tengo las siguiente situación, usando el **pluging** de **javascript** **Instascan**. Lo que esta sucediendo es que la lectura de la imagen del código QR me la esta dando invertida, lo cual se puede ver con el texto de abajo del QR. Esto me esta provocando que se me haga lenta la lectura del código QR.  A continuación le dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Nota: las pruebas las estoy haciendo con una tablet android 4.4.2 Lenovo

**Código:**

```
      let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
  scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
    //console.log(content);
    window.location = "index.php?c=cajas&f=etiqueta&idqr="+content; 
  });
  idCam = 1;
  Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
      var selectedCam = cameras[idCam];
      $.each(cameras, (i, c) => {
          if (c.name.indexOf('back') != -1) {
              selectedCam = c;
              return false;
          }
      });          
      scanner.start(cameras[idCam]);
    } else {
      console.error('No cameras found.');
    }
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, `Instascan.Scanner` viene por defecto con el atributo `mirror` a `true`. Para evitar esto tienes que configurarlo a `false` en el momento de instanciar el objeto:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), mirror: false });
```